# how to pass data from textview to listview items selection

Tags: java, android, listview

CarSelection.java:

```
public class CarSelection extends Activity {

private Spinner spinner1;

// array list for spinner adapter
private ArrayList<Category> brandsList;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Url to get all categories
private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://10.0.2.2/view/get_brands.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_selection);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b != null){
        String selection1=b.getString("pickup");
        String selection2=b.getString("pickdate");
        String selection3=b.getString("picktime");
        String selection4=b.getString("dropoff");
        String selection5=b.getString("dropdate");
        String selection6=b.getString("droptime");
        TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pickup);     
        TextView text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pickdate);
        TextView text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.picktime);
        TextView text4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
        TextView text5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dropdate);
        TextView text6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.droptime);
        text1.setText(selection1);
        text2.setText(selection2);
        text3.setText(selection3);
        text4.setText(selection4);
        text5.setText(selection5);
        text6.setText(selection6);
        }

        else{
            Toast.makeText(CarSelection.this,"Haven't Received any data yet",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    brandsList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    new GetCategories().execute(); 
}
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerbrand);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CarBrandSelection(this));

      }
...
}
```

CarBrandSelection.java:

```
public class CarBrandSelection implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private TextView pdestination, pdate, ptime, ddestination, ddate, dtime;
Activity mActivity;
public CarBrandSelection(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
 }

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

     switch(pos){
        case 1:

            pdestination=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickup);
            pdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickdate);
            ptime=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.picktime);
            ddestination=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
            ddate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dropdate);
            dtime=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.droptime);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("destination", pdestination.getText().toString());

           Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, FirstListView.class);
           intent.putExtras(b);
           mActivity.startActivity(intent);

           break;
        case 2:
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(mActivity, SecondListView.class);
           mActivity.startActivity(intent1);
           break;
        case 3:
               Intent intent2 = new Intent(mActivity, ThirdListView.class);
               mActivity.startActivity(intent2);
               break;
        case 4:
               Intent intent3 = new Intent(mActivity, FourthListView.class);
               mActivity.startActivity(intent3);
               break;
        // and so on 
        // .....

      }
  }
  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  }    
}
```

FirstListView.java:

```
public class FirstListView extends Activity implements FetchDataListener{

private ProgressDialog dialog;

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);     

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String selection1=b.getString("destination");
    TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.p_destination);   
    text1.setText(selection1);

    initView(); 
    addListenerOnListItemSelection();
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="235dp"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linealayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/p_destination"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/drop_off" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

activity_car_selection.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".CarSelection" >

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/vehicle_brand"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/pickup"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/pickdate"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/picktime"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          />


 <TextView android:id="@+id/dropoff"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/dropdate"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/droptime"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text=""
          />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I really need help to solve this problem. I want to do like when a user clicks on a specific item in the spinner (`R.id.spinnerbrand`), the data from the textview (`R.id.pickup`) will be passed to the next activity which is `FirstListView.java`. I'm not sure whether I do it correctly because the data cannot be passed. Really appreciate if someone can help to solve this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data from the spinner you can use:

```
String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

And for passing the data to the other activity basically this is what you need to do:
in the first activity you should create a `Intent` set the Action and add what you need:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(tag, value);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getBooleanExtra(tag, defaultValue);
intent.getStringExtra(tag, defaultValue);
intent.getIntegerExtra(tag, defaultValue);
```

one of the get-functions will give return you the value, depending on the datatype you are passing through.

or in the second activity, for example i want to get the value of name that I include at:
`intent.putExtra("name", name);` on first class, for that you can simply make:

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b = getIntent().getExtras();
 String name = b.getString("name");
```

Comment: Martinezfor an ordinary activity, i can apply your method.However, in my coding there are four spinner selection which lead to different activity (case 1,2,3,4) as shown above.I'm not sure where to put the intent correctly in my coding.

Comment: @user3402438 You should add the intent on all the cases that requieres a change of  activity, as I see if pos=1 the activity is `FirstListView`, pos=2 the activity is `SecondListView` if you have 4 posibilities you need 4 different `Intents`

Comment: but there are errors with the findviewbyid in case1.I try to fix this by adding extends Activity.Then, i try to run it and unfortunately has stopped when i click on an item in spinner that is linked to FirstListView.java.Pls guide me the correct way to solve this

Comment: can you post the error log? and the xml of the activity

Comment: can run already for now...but no data being pass to main_activity.xml.I want to pass data from textview(R.id.pickup) to textview(R.id.p_destination).I have posted the xml above..

Comment: which is main activity and wich is the activity you want to send to?

Comment: the main_activity.xml is belongs to FirstListView.java.You can refer to the above code. I have posted everything at the above

Comment: Your code is really weird, and I think that you don´t know well how spinner works. Read this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/spinner/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)